# bubble sort ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
public static void sort(int[] array){
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < (array.length); i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < (array.length); i++){
            if(array[i]>array[j]){
                array[j] = newArray[j-1];
                array[i] = newArray[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int idx = 0; idx < array.length; idx++){
        System.out.println(newArray[idx] + " ");
    }
}
```

Im trying to bubble sort but with this code i keep getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. What should i change to solve this problem? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second for-loop:

```
for(int j = i+1; j < (array.length); i++){
```

you increment `i++` instead of `j++`.

Comment: ah my, thank you a lot! that was a stupid mistake from my part.